# Angular application REST API call to JBoss no response - just 'stalled'

Tags: angular, jboss, config

I am trying to troubleshoot my angular app that is hitting an API running on standalone JBoss locally.

Calls to the API suddenly now just stall. This started a week ago and several of us have been blocked completely since. Even pointing at someone else's server running on their system results in the same problem.

The first call is a login: /rest/v1/userprofiles/tstbwp01. Examining the call in Chrome's Dev Tools, there's no error thrown and no response. The Timing tab says 'Stalled'. Looking up stalled, it says there are three possible reasons:

- higher priority requests.
- reached limit of six TCP connections open for this origin
- browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache

None of these make any sense. It's all I'm running, and I've tried it after a hard reboot, to see if maybe there's requests piled up or something.

I've looked through my config.json and settings.xml but I don't really know what to look for.

Frankly, there are far better systems config people in my group, and they're stumped too.

I know this is impossibly vague, and you can't troubleshoot-by-wire, but I could really use some leads as to where/what/how else to troubleshoot.

Comment: You've turned on the maximum amount of debug you can to see if its maybe JBoss's own java code getting stuck somewhere?  Note you'd end up with a TON of trace, but you can clear it just before you try the API call then save it for analysis?  Oh, and since it's REST - why not remove the possibility of Angular playing bad and try the REST request using CURL or from your browser if possible.

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Comment: Not yet. (sprint planning day)
I can bypass the angular using POSTMAN but I still get the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I handt heard of POSTMAN, I'll have to check it out - so assuming POSTMAN can just do a simple GET to your RESTful service like a CURL would do - I'm again leaning more towards something being wrong on the server side and trying to use trace/debug to find out where it hangs.  Another option is do a thread dump for JBoss - you know how to do that, i.e. if Linux (and note it cant be writing stdout to /dev/null) you do a kill -3 I believe, which doesnt cause the server to kill the process but instead dump all the heap I believe it is. Part 1

Comment: In this, you'd find your request and see it being blocked by something else using Samurai to load and navigate the dump - its a great free tool.  Other option and it could be easiest, can you debug through Eclipse or your IDE and step through the code till you see where it stalls? Part 2 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem may have had to do with a bad 'localhost' path in the config.json. Can't be sure. Copied from a colleague and it just magically worked. Can't see any diff. I hate that.